# improve perfromance of query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite.
I have a query which gets records after going through 6 different tables.
Each table contain many records.
The query below has been written based on the PK-FK relationship, but it's taking too much time to retrieve the data.

I can't be able to do Altering, Indexing on database.

```
Select distinct A.LINK_ID as LINK_ID,
                B.POI_ID
from RDF_LINK as A,
     RDF_POI as B,
     RDF_POI_ADDRESS as c,
     RDF_LOCATION as d,
     RDF_ROAD_LINK as e,
     RDF_NAV_LINK as f
where B.[CAT_ID] = '5800'
  AND B.[POI_ID] = c.[POI_ID]
  AND c.[LOCATION_ID] = d.[LOCATION_ID]
  AND d.[LINK_ID] = A.[LINK_ID]
  AND A.[LINK_ID] = e.[LINK_ID]
  AND A.[LINK_ID] = f.[LINK_ID]
```

Am I using the wrong method? Do I need to use IN?

`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` command output ::

```
0   0   3   SCAN TABLE RDF_LOCATION AS d (~101198 rows)
0   1   0   SEARCH TABLE RDF_LINK AS A USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_RDF_LINK_1 (LINK_ID=?) (~1 rows)
0   2   5   SEARCH TABLE RDF_NAV_LINK AS f USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_RDF_NAV_LINK_1 (LINK_ID=?) (~1 rows)
0   3   4   SEARCH TABLE RDF_ROAD_LINK AS e USING COVERING INDEX NX_RDFROADLINK_LINKID (LINK_ID=?) (~2 rows)
0   4   1   SEARCH TABLE RDF_POI AS B USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (CAT_ID=?) (~7 rows)
0   5   2   SEARCH TABLE RDF_POI_ADDRESS AS c USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_RDF_POI_ADDRESS_1 (POI_ID=? AND LOCATION_ID=?) (~1 rows)
0   0   0   USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT
```

Comment: Show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html). It is likely that you need indexes.

Comment: Why are `RDF_ROAD_LINK` and `RDF_NAV_LINK` in this query?

Comment: How many rows are there in each table (and particulary with b.cat_id = 5800)?

Comment: I need LINK_ID from table A and POI_ID from B. Table A and B connected through C and D. Where I also need to check A.LINK_ID exists into table e and f.  I need to perform this in one query so I can't able to think about Indexing.

Comment: I need to check that LINK_ID from RDF_LINK is have to exists  RDF_NAV_LINK and RDF_ROAD_LINK.

Comment: Each table have million records minimum ... where as ... **Select count(*) from RDF_POI where CAT_ID = '5800'** .... output:: **543318**

Comment: @CL. .. Can I make Index for this tables and run this query in one single query ?

Comment: Why do you think that doing this in one single query would make any differenc?

Comment: @CL... As you suggested in your first reply so i guess... although all these columns which used in Where condition they are already Primary key... Above written query is taking too much time to execute.

Comment: I cannot know what is wrong until you show the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output.

Comment: @CL... I have mentioned query plan output already in forth comment.

Comment: [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) is an SQLite command, which you should run.

Comment: @CL. .. Sorry I didn't knew about this.

Comment: @CL. .. I added the output of EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `AUTOMATIC` index on `RDF_POI.CAT_ID`.
This means that the database thinks it is worthwhile to create a temporary index just for this query.
You should create this index permanently:

```
CREATE INDEX whatever ON RDF_POI(CAT_ID);
```

Furthermore, the `CAT_ID` lookup does not appear to have a high selectivity.

Run [ANALYZE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) so that the database has a better idea of the shape of your data.

Comment: Hello I am unable to decide about Indexing. Like I have below query which taking too much time for executing `select count(rn.NODE_ID) as Count, rnl.[ISO_COUNTRY_CODE] as Country, rnl.[FUNCTIONAL_CLASS] as Functional_Class 
from RDF_NODE as rn, RDF_LINK as rl, RDF_NAV_LINK as rnl 
where rl.[LINK_ID] = rnl.[LINK_ID] AND rn.NODE_ID IN (rl.[NONREF_NODE_ID], rl.[REF_NODE_ID])
GROUP BY rnl.[ISO_COUNTRY_CODE], rnl.[FUNCTIONAL_CLASS]`

Comment: While I use **EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN**  ::  `0 0 0 SCAN TABLE RDF_NODE AS rn USING COVERING INDEX NODE (~1000000 rows)
0 1 2 SCAN TABLE RDF_NAV_LINK AS rnl (~6645278 rows)
0 2 1 SEARCH TABLE RDF_LINK AS rl USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_RDF_LINK_1 (LINK_ID=?) (~1 rows)
0 0 0 EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
0 0 0 USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY`

Comment: I don't know the Index already there on RDF_NODE table and LINK_ID are primary key on both rl and rnl table, so why this query taking too much time.

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.